# Cannot set property 'text' of undefined

Tags: typescript, nativescript

[xml code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRfRU.jpg)[ScreenShot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrFwJ.jpg)i am trying to bind my label with my code and trying to set it text but whenever i run my code it shows me that Cannot set property 'text' of undefined " i tried every solution but nothing is working for me. i import everything module and almost tried every solution but it show me this error please help me to resolve this issue

here is my code

```
import { EventData, Observable } from "data/observable";
import { ObservableArray } from "data/observable-array";
import { Page} from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import { GridItemEventData } from "nativescript-grid-view";
import { veriables } from "~/veriables";
import { Button } from "tns-core-modules/ui/button";
import { Label } from "tns-core-modules/ui/label";
let viewModel: Observable = new Observable();
let txtlbl : Label;
export function pageLoaded(args: EventData) {

const page = <Page>args.object;       
const items = new ObservableArray();
var myveriable = veriables.getInstance()
const label = <Label>page.getViewById("lbl");
label.text = "NativeScript is Awesome";
// const view = require("tns-core-modules/ui/core/view");
// const testlbl = <Label>args.object;
// let parent =  testlbl.parent;
// txtlbl = view.getViewById(parent,"lbl");

// const vm = new Observable();
// vm.set("title", "100");

// label.textWrap = true;
// label.textAlignment = "center";
//page.bindingContext = vm;
var NumberOnelist : number[] = new Array();
var NumberTwolist : number[] = new Array();
var NumberOfQuestions :number;
var Anslist       : number[] = new Array();
var Operator      : string;
NumberOnelist = myveriable.NumberOneArraylist;
NumberTwolist = myveriable.NumberTwoArraylist;
NumberOfQuestions = myveriable.NumberofQuestions;
Anslist       = myveriable.AnswerArrayList;
Operator      = myveriable.Operator;

for (let loop = 0; loop <NumberOfQuestions; loop++) {
   items.push(NumberOfQuestions);
}
viewModel = new Observable();
viewModel.set("items", items);
page.bindingContext = viewModel;
}



export function gridViewItemTap(args: GridItemEventData) {
console.log("tap index " + args.index.toString());
}

export function gridViewItemLoading(args: GridItemEventData) {
  console.log("item loading " + args.index.toString());
}

export function gridViewLoadMoreItems(args: EventData) {
console.log("load more items");
}
```

Comment: Share yout html , you are you giving id `lbl` to label?

Comment: <Label id="lbl" text="{{ title }}" textWrap="true" />

Comment: May be you are trying to early before label is avaiable. Let the page load then try to change the text

Comment: tried but not working same issue

Comment: instead of const label = <Label>page.getViewById("lbl"); try let label = <Label>page.getViewById("lbl");

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: I don't see any label with id `lbl` in your XML (referring to the XML screenshot in your question). Would you mind posting your exact XML code if it's updated.

Comment: sory latr i had remove this but now i figure out my problem but it's still not set value of label using getViewById because my label is inside the gridview if you can figure out this i will be thank full to you

Answer (score 0):

Check your code is "lbl" is available or not?

```
<Label id="lbl" text="{{ title }}" textWrap="true" />
```

Comment: yes (<Label id="lbl" text="{{ title }}" textWrap="true" />)

Comment: where u written this code ?
const label = <Label>page.getViewById("lbl");
 label.text = "NativeScript is Awesome";

Comment: check my question again i have posted the full source code

Comment: export function onPageLoaded(args) {
  const label = <Label>page.getViewById("lbl");
  label.text = "NativeScript is Awesome";
}

Comment: please check my question again i have added the screenshot of my error btw i have tried your solution but still the same error

Comment: check my question again i have added the screenshot of my xml code

Comment: Please follow the link below, https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/page

OR
Try like this

import { EventData } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

export function onPageLoaded(args: EventData): void {
    console.log("Page Loaded");
    const page = args.object as Page;
}

the onPageLoaded will fire after loaded the dom elements, there is some gap between the loading dom elements and script loading so that you are getting this error.